# "Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success'" error parsing json response

Tags: php, json

im using google recaptcha and the way of my validation is through ajax, everything is working, I got a response

```
{
success: "false/true"
}
```

but i got an error saying "Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success" on line 30, any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations?

this is my code on the controller (the one i use in communicating the google recaptcha API)

```
$captcha=$request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=mysitekey&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response.success == false) //this is the line 30
{
    return 'You are spammer ! Get the out';
}else{
    return 'Thanks for posting comment.';
}
```

this is the line 30 "$response.success == false"

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump the response?

Comment: @Szenis: i got this "string '{
  "success": false
}' (length=22)"

Comment: I think alex his answer is what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a couple of steps.
First you need to `json_decode` the response you get from the API

```
$responseData = json_decode($response);
```

Next you need to properly address the "success" element from which I assume will be an array, but you will verify this with a `var_dump()`.

```
var_dump($responseData);
```

If you get an array then the `if` clause will look like this:

```
if ($responseData["success"]==false)
```

On the other hand if you get an object in the `responseData`, the `if clause will look like this

```
if ($responseData->success==false)
```

The `dot` notation is for javascript, in `php` the `dot` is a concatentation operator.

Comment: i got this "string '{
  "success": false
}' (length=22)"

Comment: i think you meant this comment for @Szenis :) if you did what i suggested above you couldn't have gotten a `string` because `json_decode` doesn't return that

Comment: i got this one "object(stdClass)[163]
  public 'success' => boolean true" when trying yours

Comment: ok, so you got an object, use the `if` clause that I suggested in case you get an object

Comment: i tried the object parsing you gave but i got this error "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given." but if return false when the json response from the api is false. any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87957/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-code-demon).